# Convert Amazon AMI to VMware image

Tags: vmware-player, amazon-ami

How can I convert an amazon ami image to a vmware image I can run locally in vmware player?

Answer (score 6):

If you still have access to the instance, I believe the simplest way would be using "dd" to copy it off to a raw file (possibly just directly piping over SSH to the destination system like in `ssh your.ec2-syst.em 'dd if=/dev/sdh bs=1M | gzip' | gunzip | dd of=/tmp/ec2-image.raw`) and then using something like [qemu-img](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#qemu_005fimg_005finvocation) to convert the raw image to a VMDK file.

Comment: Yep.  This is the only way to do it.

Comment: Any recommended articles, blogs that shows how to use qemu-img to create VMDK file that runs in VMware player?

Comment: Umm. `qemu-img convert -f raw -O vmdk /tmp/ec2-image.raw /tmp/ec2-image.vmdk`. Maybe the [QEMU wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images) could be of some further help, if you still are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are ok to mount it locally, but not to RUN it locally. This is much more hard to achieve. [This](http://linux.blogs.com.np/2010/04/05/how-to-move-a-virtual-machine-from-ec2-to-virtualbox-or-kvm/) post seems to show a way to do this, even if grub instructions are not very clear to a novice as I am.

The author of [this](https://serverfault.com/q/364470/134120) other post is much more skeptic about the ease to do this process and suggest to build up the server from scratch.

[This](https://preda.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/downloading-an-amazon-ec2-ami-to-local-drive/) post clarifies step by step how to mount the AMI locally, but doesn't solve the booting issues.

Hope this helps!