# Converting an EC2 AMI to vmdk image

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualbox, kernel, disk-image

I've come quite close to getting Amazon Linux to boot inside VirtualBox, thanks to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/319949/convert-amazon-ami-to-vmware-image) and [these](http://linux.blogs.com.np/2010/04/05/how-to-move-a-virtual-machine-from-ec2-to-virtualbox-or-kvm/) [websites](http://church.cs.virginia.edu/genprog/index.php/Converting_an_EC2_AMI_to_a_VirtualBox_.vdi). A quick overview of the steps I've taken:

1. Launch EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2011.09 64-bit AMI
2. `dd` the contents of the EBS volume over `ssh` to a local image file.
3. Mount the image file as a loopback device and then to a local mount point.
4. Create a new empty disk image file, partition with an offset for a bootloader, and create an ext4 filesystem.
5. Mount the new image's partition and copy everything from the EC2 image.
6. Install grub (using Ubuntu's `grub-legacy-ec2` package, not grub2).
7. Convert the image file to vmdk using `qemu-img`.
8. Create a new VirtualBox VM with the vmdk.

Now the VM boots, grub loads, and the kernel is found. But it fails when it tries to mount the root device:

```
dracut Warning: No root device "block:/dev/xvda1" found
 
dracut Warning: Boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.
 
 
dracut Warning: Signal caught!
 
dracut Warning: Boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.35.14-107.1.39.amzn1.x86_64 #1
```

I have tried changing `/boot/grub/menu.lst` to find the root device by label and UUID, but nothing works. I'm guessing the xen kernel is not compatible with VirtualBox.

The reasoning behind all this effort is to make a Vagrant box that is as close to possible as the production enviroment, so deploys can be tested locally. I know it's cheap to do test runs on EC2, but poor connectivity often ruins the experience. Plus it would be really nice to have a virtual machine with the production environment so that co-workers don't have to install everything under the sun just to get up and running with app development.

If I were to try running a different kernel, what kernel could I get to be as close as possible to Amazon Linux 2011.09?

Comment: Was doing work similar to you and found the solution on other link .. sharing with you as well. Tested this and it worked for me ... http://blog.zorangagic.com/2015/03/converting-ec2-ami-to-virtualbox-vdi.html?view=snapshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried so much and I was giving up, but at the end I succeed!

**I've managed to boot with an Amazon Linux AMI ported under vmware!**

I'm almost a newby, but I did it, after hours of trials, **substituting the original amazon kernel with a vmlinuz-2.6.32-38-generic** taken from an ubuntu 64 10.04 distro.

I just get a lot of errors because the amazon configuration inside the AMI is looking for something in an internal address that obviously it doesn't find. It's the /usr/bin/cloud-init, I think.

But I can login inside, and it seems that everything is working!

Thanks for your help!!

I've written [**this**](https://preda.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/downloading-an-amazon-ec2-ami-to-local-drive/) blogpost with step by step instructions to migrate from AMI to Vmware.

Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW, Reed, I arrived exactly at the point you stated (dracut telling "no root device found"... did you move any further??

Comment: I came to basically the same solution you did: copying the kernel from Ubuntu. It works, but at that point I don't know how similar the system will perform to the Amazon Linux AMI.

Comment: Please also see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28201388/675721), which provides 2 alternative updated methods for exporting to VirtualBox/VMWare VMDK, as well as instructions on using your newly created VMDK with Vagrant

Answer (score 2):

The official kernel Amazon derived theirs in their 2011.09 distribution, *ie* 2.6.35.14.

You can probably get the source package for the Amazon one with `get_reference_source`, but I wouldn't expect it to work outside of Amazon anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The people over at Cloudify have shared how they create a VirtualBox ready Vagrant box, without access to bare metal machines - they use AWS.

9 steps to heaven:

- Create a source image (AMI) [...] using Packer.
- Launch a worker instance in AWS with the snapshot or source image as one of its disks.
- On the worker image: Create a raw image volume as a file and create an ext4 partition on it.
- Copy over the data from the source image disk to the previously created ext4 partition.
- Install the bootloader (extlinux) on the ext4 partition.
- Convert the raw image into a VMDK.
- Bundle the VMDK using an OVF descriptor and Vagrant metadata and create a tar file with the content and .box extension.
- Upload to S3 [or whatever you like].
- Clean up.

> **Source**: Blog post at http://www.developer.com/design/creating-a-reproducible-and-portable-development-environment.html with the above 9 steps
>
> **Code**: https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-packager/tree/3.2m4/image-builder